# "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" within React, what's wrong here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Trying to get my head around props so forgive me if its a silly mistake. I am trying to pass all of my data into one variable and pass that out into props (using {item.text} and {item.key}), however, my ".map" isn't picking up anything and there's a bunch of errors, what's wrong with my code?

The problem lays specifically here in this block of code

```
      createList(list) {
        return <li>{list.text}</li>
      }

      render() {

        var entries = this.state.list
        var finalEntries = entries.props.map(this.createList)
```

Here is the code in full

```
    import React from "react";
    import "./App.css";
    import { isTemplateElement } from "@babel/types";

    class TodoListt extends React.Component {
      state = {};

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          userInput: "",
          list: [],
        };
      }

      changeUserInput(input) {
        this.setState({
          userInput: input
        })
      }


      addToList(input) {
        let listArray = this.state.list;
        listArray.push(input);
        var newItem = {
          text: listArray,
          key: Date.now()
        };

        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            list: prevState.list.concat(newItem)
          };
        });

        this.setState({
          list: listArray
        })


      }

      createList(list) {
        return <li>{list.text}</li>
      }

      render() {

        var entries = this.state.list
        var finalEntries = entries.props.map(this.createList)


        return (
          <div className="to-do-list-main">
            <input
              onChange={(e) => this.changeUserInput(e.target.value)}
              value={this.state.userInput}
              type="text"
            />
            <button onClick={() => this.addToList(this.state.userInput)}>Press me</button>
            <ul>
              {this.testingSetup()}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default TodoListt;
```

Comment: Your map code makes no sense. You're looking for the `props` key in `this.state.list`, but that's an _array_, so it doesn't have keys. Do you just mean `this.state.list.map(blah)`?

Comment: Also in `addToList` you're mutating your state which you shouldn't do in React. Arrays are stored by *reference* in JS, so `let listArray = this.state.list;` doesn't create a clone of the array, it creates another variable with a reference to that same array. Hence when you subsequently call `listArray.push(input);`, you're mutating the array in state. You can print `this.state.list` on the next line and see that it has the pushed value in it.

Comment: Basically, I want the outcome to be that I can grab all the info from the list after I push an item to it ( the text and the key), and then map it together and use {item.key} and {item.text}, how would I achieve this? Sorry I am new to React

Comment: My Variable newItem pulls the input from the input box, and creates 2 props, text and key

Comment: I've added an answer with a basic example. Just another point, be careful using the word `props` in React, it has a specific meaning. You say the button creates an object with 2 new "props", but really it's an object with 2 new *properties*. That's what they are, object properties. They're not related to React's `props` in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, early doors with React, I am sure I will get there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the spread operator to add to an existing array. Simply add a new object to the array in the state, and then clear the user input, ready for another item. Based on your code, here's a simple example of adding to a state list (haven't run myself, so just check for syntax errors and such):

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { isTemplateElement } from "@babel/types";

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userInput: "",
      list: [],
    };
  }

  changeUserInput(input) {
    this.setState({
      userInput: input
    })
  }


  addToList() {
    const { list, userInput } = this.state;
    // Add item to state list using spread operator and clear input
    this.setState({
      list: [...list, {text:userInput, key: Date.now()}],
      userInput: ""
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="to-do-list-main">
        <input
          onChange={(e) => this.changeUserInput(e.target.value)}
          value={this.state.userInput}
          type="text"
        />
        <button onClick={() => this.addToList()}>Press me</button>

        <hr/>

        {/* For each item in the list, render the contents */}
        {this.state.list.map(item => (
          <div key={item.key}>
            <h3>{item.text}</h3>
            <p>Time: {item.key}</p>
          </div>
        ))}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoList;
```